# How can I install scikit-image without internet?

Tags: python, c++, windows, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I want to install scikit-image on a Windows 7 machine that does not have an internet connection. I went [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) and downloaded the .zip file, moved into onto the machine, extracted it and tried to install it but Cython is a requirement. So then I went [here](http://cython.org/#download) and tried the same for Cython but I can't install Cython because I don't have GCC on that comptuer. I can't install MinGW because I need to extract .tar.x files which require a 3rd-party extraction program like 7zip, which I **cannot** install on this comptuer (the one with internet). I can't install scikit-image on the machine via a .whl file because it doesn't have pip or easy_install. I can't install pip or easy_install on it because it doesn't have internet.

In short, to somehow install scikit-image on the offline Windows 7 machine I need to:

1. Install a compiler so I can compile Cython (I cannot unzip the files to do this)
2. Install Cython (I have the files to do this)
3. Possibly install another requirement, six (I don't think I need to install this)
4. Install scikit-image via `python setup.py install` (I have the files to do this)

It is so unbelievably frustrating working with a machine without internet. If someone has precompiled win32 scikit-image binaries please let me know where to find them. I tried [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image) but they are all .whl files.

Comment: Either install Anaconda, or try these binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Create virtual machine with Linux.